# difficulty passing Japanese characters(UTF-8) via json_encode

Tags: php, json, utf-8

Having problems returning a list of Japanese terms from an MSSql database as JSON.
If I return them as a bunch of list items all is ok, but I can not seem to get json encode to work for me.
Any pointers much appreciated.

```
$prefs = array();
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
{
$prefs[] =  mb_convert_encoding($row["Pref"] , "UTF-8", "SHIFT-JIS") ; 
    //echo "<li>" . mb_convert_encoding($row["Pref"] , "UTF-8", "SHIFT-JIS") . "</li>";
}

 echo json_encode($prefs);
```

Comment: Nope - just get a JSON encoded array of goggledygook. ["\u611b\u77e5\u770c","\u611b\u5a9b\u770c"]

Comment: This looks totally valid to me. Those are unicode escape sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\u611b\u77e5\u770c = 愛知県　(Aichi Prefecture)

\u611b\u5a9b\u770c = 愛媛県  (Ehime Prefecture)

Both are correct Japanese Prefecture name.
 So string conversion part has no problem.

The perp is hiding in the later phase.

Comment: Thanks - all sorted. Actually ended up being a cross domain issue and like you said the Japanese was fine.