# How to store a Japanese Character in json_encode?

Tags: sql, utf-8, json

I'm trying to save a json_encoded strings to the database but whenever i do i get this:

```
u30abu30bf
```

when saving:

```
カタ
```

how do i decode such a thing?

tried php utf8_decode and encode but i doesn't seem to work,
i also tried reading the threads below:

1. [PHP decoding and encoding json with unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381900/php-decoding-and-encoding-json-with-unicode-characters)
2. [difficulty passing Japanese characters(UTF-8) via json_encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051287/difficulty-passing-japanese-charactersutf-8-via-json-encode)

**here is a var_dump data of $flex_encoded before passing it as a parameter:**

```
//this one seems to passing the right encoding
[{"japanese_name":"\u30ca\u30ab\u30cd"},{"japanese_name":"\u30ca\u30ab\u30cd"}]
```

**here is the function call:**

```
$this->updateFlexData($game_id, $flex_encoded);
```

**here is the function for updating my db:**

```
function updateFlexData($game_id, $json_data)
{
    $arrVal = array(
        'json_data'=> $json_data,
    );

    Db::getInstance()->autoExecute('japanese_names', $arrVal, 'UPDATE', " game_id = '".$game_id."'", false);
}
```

**database column type is:**

```
`json_data` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
```

**my PHP version:**

PHP Version 5.3.10

Comment: can you show us the code you got please

Comment: I'd guess this is a combination of [Reference: Why are my “special” Unicode characters encoded weird using json_encode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745662/reference-why-are-my-special-unicode-characters-encoded-weird-using-json-enco) plus you're somehow stripping out the backslashes somewhere.

Comment: and can you tell us your php version pls

Comment: @FelixLahmer just updated the thread with some info you requested, sorry it took some time. i left from work after posting this.

Comment: @deceze - yes its somehow stripping the backlashes i do think its the problem with the update function.

Comment: I believe you need to read http://kunststube.net/escapism.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after hours of tinkering with the code i somehow made it to work:
ok its maybe not the solution but:

1. when i proceed to storing **json_data** with this content(below) decoding **json_data** from database   results to parse error because of the extra " **quotations**

   ```
   $japanese_name = json_encode($japanese_text); //returns "\u30ca\u30ab\u30cd"
   ```
2. i just removed the " from each sides to make it just **\u30ca\u30ab\u30cd** and then proceeded to store in the db

   ```
   $jp = str_replace("\"","",$japanese_name); //returns \u30ca\u30ab\u30cd
   ```

Comment: -1 Your only problem is that you're not escaping the data correctly for use in an SQL statement.

Answer (score 14):

Try [JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

And instead of this `\u7537\u6027\u304c\u5f7c\u5973\u306b\u7740\u3066\...` you're going to get `男性が彼...`